# Data is empty when passing a variable from JS to PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to pass a simple string variable with an onclick event, the request is successful but I get an empty response on the console, and the `xvar` variable is no coming through so I get the "NO DATA" `p` tag. This is my first time using Ajax so I tried to make it very simple to start. Here's my code:

**JS**

```
    var xvar = 'D';
    $('.test').click( () => {
        $.ajax({
            data: { xvar : xvar },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'test.php', 
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                console.log('Success: '+data)
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("The request failed."+errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

**test.PHP**

```
$xvar = (isset($_POST['xvar'])) ? $_POST['xvar'] : '<p>NO DATA</p>';
echo $xvar;
```

I'm using JQuery 3.5.1 that is included with Wordpress. I'll appreciate any feedback.

**EDIT**
I managed to get the response on `test.php` as seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4sLk.png):

But I when I try to render the value with `print_r` is not shown.

```
$res = $_POST;
print_r($res);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you verify the exact version of jQuery that's included? You should be able to see it in the page source. Side note: it's not necessary to define a key when it's the same name as your variable. Just specifying `data: { xvar }` should be enough.

Comment: You really can just define `data: { xvar }`, but it is not recommended because in some browsers this result in a "':' expected error", like IE.

Comment: It's JQuery 1.12.4

Comment: Use the Network tab of the browser's developer tool to look at the Ajax request and its raw response. What do you see?

Comment: I got this response ```{"wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1608029785}``` from admin-ajax.php. "This request has no data available" from test.php.

Comment: On the headers tab inside the Network tab I found that Form data has the variable. So it appears to be coming through, but still don't know why php doesn't pick it up.

Comment: *"This request has no data available" from test.php* but the console still logs `<p>NO DATA</p>'`?

Comment: That correct Quentin.

Comment: Even with 1.12.4 I can't reproduce using the code in the question.

Comment: I updated jquery to 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

On the `data` of your Ajax, try to add the quotes in the key of the data. Like this:

```
data: { "xvar" : xvar },
```

Comment: This should not affect the outcome.